# Some questions about dotnetopenauth

Tags: twitter, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I have a couple outstanding questions mainly reguarding twitter and facebook

1. In the FacebookGraph class there are properties such as Id,name,etc. I am wondering how do I add to this list? Like what happens if I want a users hometown? I tried to add a property called hometown but it always is null.
2. What should I store their id(1418) or the whole url(http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1418) for lookup later in my db to grab their data and to see if they have an account with my site?
3. Is it actually good to use this id as it seems like it is common knowledge. Can't someone just find the profile id or whatever and do a fake request on my site?
4. how do you setup dotnetopenauth to deal with the case when a user goes to facebook and deletes access to my website. I know you can send a deauthorization code to your site and then delete their account but I don't know how to do that through dotnetopenauth

Twitter

1. Is it possible to do number 4 with twitter?

Ajax

1. Is it possible to make the openid stuff ajax? I don't see a sample anywhere in the dotnetopenauth samples.

Comment: I strongly suggest you break this question up into at least 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no pro at Facebook.  But the FacebookGraph class is in the ApplicationBlock, which ships as source and is fully intended for you to customize or extend within your own application.  Hopefully people more familiar with Facebook in particular, or the Facebook docs, can help you with those questions.

Since Facebook is *not* OpenID, what you store whether ID # or the whole URL, is less critical.  People should not be able to just craft requests to log in as others because your site *should* be verifying signatures, etc.  If you're using DotNetOpenAuth appropriately this is probably being done automatically for you.  But without seeing your code it can't be said for sure.

Assume the id is common knowledge.  It certainly isn't a long random number so anyone can guess it.  The ID must be accompanied by a signature that verifies that Facebook sent the ID, just now, for you.

I suspect the deauthorization code isn't going to be relevant to DotNetOpenAuth -- that's probably just some URL that you respond to.  But again, I haven't read the FB docs on this.

Here's the real answer I *can* give you.  Yes, OpenID  works with AJAX reasonably well.  You can see some samples of this at [nerddinner.com](http://nerddinner.com) or a [sample of a blog post comment](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/openidrelyingpartywebforms/ajaxlogin.aspx) system.  The most complete AJAX demonstration for standard login may be in the [web forms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a527c9a4-6032-43ce-9284-d7e3174deb56) or [MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef) project templates available on the Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: How would I go about extending it. I am not even sure how it works. I am not sure how I could ask it is even asking for the information nor how it gets it from the stream. I tried add like "hometown" to the facebookgraph class but it is always null. As for verifying signatures I am basically using the sample that came with 3.5 so if that is done properly then I guess verification should be working. Does the library throw an error if the signature does not match or how does it know it is a valid signature